# Else is never reached in python

Tags: python

I only have to do this:

1. Take a string entered by the user and print the game grid as in the previous stage.
2. Analyze the game state and print the result.

Like this:

```
1. Enter cells: XXXOO__O_    ---------  
| X X X |  
| O O _ |  
| _ O _ |    ---------
 X wins
```

The problem is that my program never reaches the elif statements and I don´t know why.

```
n = input()
number_grid = []
Winner = ""
print("---------")
Cont = {"X": 0, "O": 0, "_": 0}   # This will count to check for impossible games
for i in range(0, len(n), 3):
    print("|", n[i], n[i+1], n[i+2], "|")
    number_grid.append([n[i], n[i+1], n[i+2]])
    Cont[n[i]] = Cont[n[i]] + 1
    Cont[n[i + 1]] = Cont[n[i + 1]] + 1
    Cont[n[i + 2]] = Cont[n[i + 2]] + 1
print("---------")

Impossible = False
if 2 <= Cont["X"] - Cont["O"] or Cont["X"] - Cont["O"] <= -2:
    Impossible = True
    print("Impossible")
    exit()
if Winner == "" and Impossible is False:
    for rows in range(0, 3):    # Check winner in rows
        if number_grid[rows][0] == number_grid[rows][1] == number_grid[rows][2] != "_":
            Winner = number_grid[rows][0]
            print(Winner, "wins")
    for columns in range(0, 3):  # Check winner in columns
        if number_grid[0][columns] == number_grid[1][columns] == number_grid[2][columns] != "_":
            Winner = number_grid[0][columns]
            print(Winner, "wins")
    if number_grid[0][0] == number_grid[1][1] == number_grid[2][2] != "_":  # Check winner in first diagonal
        Winner = number_grid[0][0]
        print(Winner, "wins")
    if number_grid[0][2] == number_grid[1][1] == number_grid[2][0] != "_":  # Check winner in second diagonal
        Winner = number_grid[0][2]
        print(Winner, "wins")
elif Cont["_"] != 0:
    print("Game not finished")
elif Cont["X"] + Cont["O"] == 9:
    print("Draw")
```

Comment: There isn't any kind of loop in your code to cause it to run more than once, therefore the if condition is only checked once - before any of the code that could cause `Winner` to be equal to anything other than `""`. For future reference, please read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and try to solve problems yourself, by thinking through the logic of the code, explicitly saying what you think is true at every step, and *testing whether those assumptions are correct*.

Comment: Also, please note that the [basic] tag is for questions about code written in the BASIC programming language, **not** for questions that "are basic". Since this isn't a discussion forum, we aren't interested in classifying questions by how difficult the concepts are and we don't care about how experienced you are in the language when you ask the question. We care about things that make it easier the question to come up in search engine results, when someone else has the same problem (which also means we care about how likely it is that someone else has the same problem).

Comment: You should also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example . Often it becomes obvious where the logical problem is, when try to remove everything that *isn't* related to causing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reducing your code down...

```
Winner = ""
Impossible = False
if Winner == "" and Impossible is False:
    # Stuff
elif Cont["_"] != 0:
    print("Game not finished")
elif Cont["X"] + Cont["O"] == 9:
    print("Draw")
```

In your current code, it's not possible for `Winner != ""` or  `Impossible != True`. So you will never enter the elif statement.